# Lucene Like Search engine for leaflet

Tags: leaflet, search, lucene

I need to search my geojson file by its **feature properties** (*which were **fields** on the csv file before I converted it*).

I found [this search plugin](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search) but it doesn't meet my needs.

I need a search engine like *lucene* in elasticsearch that returns to me all the GPS points with a specific condition.

Is that possible?
If yes how?

Edit :
 this is an example of geojson files :

```
{"features": [{"geometry": {"coordinates": [40.81072617, -73.95240784], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {}, "type": "Feature"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [40.71183395, -73.96302032], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {}, "type": "Feature"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [40.75595093, -73.84346008], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {}, "type": "Feature"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [40.75424576, -73.92481232], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {}, "type": "Feature"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [40.75645065, -73.92950439], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {}, "type": "Feature"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [40.76170349, -73.9250412], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {}, "type": "Feature"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [40.74570465, -73.90320587], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {}, "type": "Feature"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [40.72134018, -73.84425354], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {}, "type": "Feature"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [40.70240021, -73.98892975], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {}, "type": "Feature"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [40.8044548, -73.95552826], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {}, "type": "Feature"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [40.71715546, -73.95846558], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {}, "type": "Feature"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [40.75831223, -73.9287262], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {}, "type": "Feature"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [40.74129486, -73.90457916], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {}, "type": "Feature"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [40.80869675, -73.94830322], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {}, "type": "Feature"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [40.8042717, -73.93263245], "type": "Point"}, "properties": {}, "type": "Feature"}], "type": "FeatureCollection"}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of your geojson file?

Comment: Maybe [Defiant.js](http://defiantjs.com/) is something for you.